# iOS control delay in updating

Tags: ios, uislider

When the user presses a button in my app a call is made to an object to process some data.  When this is complete I try to update a control (text field or uislider) with a value that I get from this class.

The NSLog message just before this call to set the value is displayed but it takes about 10 seconds to update the control on the screen.

The CPU is idle and the memory consumption is not changing.

Why is there a delay to update the control and how to I correct?

Comment: Make sure you're updating the UI on the main thread

Comment: Can you show or paste your source code here?

Comment: @Shai - yes, I thought this might be an issue.  I now call within:     `[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^ {         [self.slider setValue:level]; }`

Comment: try     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
...